# SimpleDateFormat is behaving strange in Android

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

Following is the code that I have used to get the 00 hour of the current day (in long format).

I am running the below code in android.

The method returns the value properly most of the time. But once in a while it returns the value of **System.currentTimeMillis()**.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public static final SimpleDateFormat SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


public static long getLongForCurrent00hr() {
    Date date = new Date();
    String time = SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR.format(date);

    long value;
    try {
        Date date2 = SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR .parse(time);
        value = date2.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        value = 0;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Why is it returning the **System.currentTimeMillis()**?
How can I solve the issue?

I am more interested in knowing WHY..

As I was ruuning this code today, I checked it by putting Logs:

Most of the time it returns: 1462386600000

And few times **System.currentTimeMillis()** like 1462430867302.

Comment: Your posted code does not define `pFormat` or `pDateString`.

Comment: @MikeM.fixed, check the edit

Comment: Can't reproduce...

Comment: Your posted code does not define `pDateString`.

Comment: You could be running into the issue that simple date format is not threadsafe, and it's better to instantiate it where you use it.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry fixed it again

Comment: @EpicPandaForce was that the reason it was returing the value of System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: @assylias I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @OnePunchMan I meant that running your code seems to produce the correct output and I can't reproduce your problem. But a concurrency issue is indeed a possibility.

Comment: @OnePunchMan What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to determine the first moment of the day, and then capture the count of milliseconds from epoch for that moment?

Answer (score 0):

## Your example code works

I see no problem with your code, as you frame it (read below for criticism).

Nearly your exact code is shown here. Two changes:

- I made your format constant a local variable. (simply to make this demo easier, one block of code that can be copy-pasted)
- I added a couple calls to get an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Similar to `java.util.Date`, but `Instant::toString` creates a string showing UTC rather than confusingly applying the JVM’s current time zone. So you can more clearly see that you are indeed getting the first moment of the day of your JVM’s current default time zone. In my case when running this code, my JVM’s current default time zone is `America/Los_Angeles`, currently in Daylight Saving Time (DST) for an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) for `-07:00` (seven hours behind UTC).

Example code.

```
Date date1 = new Date ();
SimpleDateFormat SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR = new SimpleDateFormat ( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
String time = SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR.format ( date1 );

Date date2 = null;
long value;
try {
    date2 = SD_FORMAT_DAY_MONTH_YEAR.parse ( time );
    value = date2.getTime ();
} catch ( ParseException e ) {
    value = 0;
}
System.out.println ( "date1: " + date1 + " date2: " + date2 + " value: " + value + " | instant 1: " + date1.toInstant () + " | instant 2: " + date2.toInstant () );
```

When run.

> date1: Thu May 05 16:55:40 PDT 2016 date2: Thu May 05 00:00:00 PDT 2016 value: 1462431600000 | instant 1: 2016-05-05T23:55:40.907Z | instant 2: 2016-05-05T07:00:00Z

## Working too hard

Your Question is confusing, but it seems that you are trying to capture the first moment of the day. You are going about it the wrong way, and are working too hard.

## Time Zone

Your code appears to be working with the `java.util.Date` class. That class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC.

But you are not getting the first moment of the day in UTC. When you parse that date-only string to generate a new `java.util.Date` (a date *plus* time-of-day value, despite the misleading name), your JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly. Very confusing to have time zones invisibly injected into the process.

Instead you should consciously consider time zones, and always make the time zone explicit is your coding (as seen below).

## java.time

The old `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar` classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality is [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [further adapted for Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. While not storing a time zone, determining a date such as “today” requires a time zone. If omitted, your JVM’s current default time zone is applied (beware, that default can change at any moment during runtime).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

You seem to want the first moment of the day. Do not assume the time of that moment is `00:00:00.0`. While often true, in some time zones an anomaly such as Daylight Saving Time may shift to another time. Let java.time determine the correct time. Calling [`atStartOfDay][2]` generates a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for the first moment appropriate to the specified time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

I strongly recommend against using handling date-time values as a count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). That is like using an array of ints of Unicode code points rather than using the String-related classes for handling text. But if you insist, you can convert. But beware data loss as the java.time classes have a finer resolution of nanoseconds whereas you are asking for milliseconds (one of many reasons to avoid handling date-time as a count-from-epoch). First extract an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
long millisecondsFromEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli(); // WARNING: Possible data loss (going from nanoseconds to milliseconds).
```

## UTC

If you did want the first moment of the day in UTC, that too is easy.

You could specify UTC as the time zone, using the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC). (That constant happens to be in [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html), a subclass of [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).)

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

But that may not be the most appropriate route. A time zone is an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) *plus* a set of rules for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). UTC has no such anomalies by definition. So more appropriate would be the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
OffsetTime ot = OffsetTime.of( 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime odt = today.atTime( ot );
```